# Remove Marker - Google Maps Javascript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying out tha Maps API. I got stuck at removing markers.
Adding Marker works great, but deletion isnt working.
Any idea why this would not work? Thank in advance!

```
function placeMarker(event) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      clickable: true,
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map
    });
  }

  function deleteMarker() {
    marker.setMap(null);
    marker = null;
  }

   function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: home
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'rightclick', placeMarker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', deleteMarker);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: marker is local to the placeMarker function, can't be accessed in deleteMarker.

Comment: thought about that, but shouldnt it be accessible through the listener? if i make it global it doesnt change anything.
tried putting an alert() in the deleteMarker function for testing if it gets executed, but that doesnt happen either.

Comment: Don't you get an obvious javascript error, something like "marker is not defined"?  You _might_ be able to use "this" to access the think clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining global variables

```
var map,
    marker,
    home = new google.maps.LatLng(46.5, 13.5);
```

results in error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined      main.js:15
```

from line

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', deleteMarker);
```

`marker` is still `undefined` because it is not created and event listener cannot be attached to it. That line has to be moved to `placeMarker()` function:

```
function placeMarker(event) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        clickable: true,
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', deleteMarker);
}
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vafar/1/edit).